# Bazel sync succeed but there were sync errors

Tags: intellij-idea, bazel

I'm super new to bazel.

I set up my simple project in a couple of hours. I can build apk from the console.

I installed InteliJ bazel plugin and tried to sync the project. And I got error:

```
Error:/private/var/tmp/_bazel_eugenmartynov/5c892ef7086faf980fe9c713cd0b9c27/external/androidsdk/BUILD.bazel:8:1: in @intellij_aspect//:intellij_info_bundled.bzl%intellij_info_aspect aspect on android_sdk rule @androidsdk//:sdk-28: 

Error:command succeeded, but not all targets were analyzed
```

What could be the issue? I don't have really clue what is going on. Is there an easy start crash course with bazel?

Comment: Is this Android Studio or IntelliJ? Can you try loading an app like https://github.com/google/google-authenticator-android in your set up and see if it works on there?

Comment: It is IntelliJ! Thanks for the suggestion, let me check it

Comment: @EugenMartynov Did you end up figuring out what the error was?

Comment: @nnnmmm sorry don't work with bazel now